# Can an object created by Silent Image be visibly hollow?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion

I am envisioning a scenario where you create a 15 x 15 room or building viewed through a door to have an interior.

Does the object created by Silent Image have to appear as a solid object? Or could you put a doorway in the side, and have someone walk inside of what seems to be a small cottage (Empty) without realizing it was an image until they attempt to touch/interact with something? (Place their hand on a wall, or attempt to climb stairs)

---

Silent Image Description:

> You create the image of an object, a creature, or some other visible phenomenon that is no larger than a 15-foot cube. The image appears at a spot within range and lasts for the duration. The image is purely visual; it isn't accompanied by sound, smell, or other sensory effects.

---

The possible duplicate in question :  [Can you create an illusion of empty space?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104466/can-you-create-an-illusion-of-empty-space)

This post asks whether you can create an image of air around yourself so that you would seem to be invisible. I am asking if instead you can create an image which has an inside. I don't want to hide anyone on the inside of the cottage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you create an illusion of empty space?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104466/can-you-create-an-illusion-of-empty-space)

Comment: Scope issue, intended effect is an image of one object / creature / phenomenon. In creating a room, potentially hundreds of discreet objects?

Comment: @Amethyst Wizard: Who says the cottage has to be furnished?

Comment: @ruse: I am not trying to hide in the empty space, or make an image of empty space. I just want to make an image that is hollow. Maybe it would be simpler to first imagine creating an image of an arch. I don't want to create an image with empty space under the arch. the image would only be the arch itself.

Comment: In creating an image of the interior of a room logically begs the next question of it’s content. My comment is here to simply ensure the question address’ this aspect as other readers/players might assume otherwise (that they could create a room with a table, chairs, books etc.)

Answer (score 3):

### Yes you can

If you create the illusion of something that has an inside, like a chest, a small cottage or a coach and leave an opening in it then the illusion will show that inside.

However, you can only create “an object” so your hollow object is the only one the spell can create - no gold in the chest, no table in the cottage and no cushions in the coach.

Comment: No. A cottage is (arguably) “an object” - a cottage full of stuff is multiple objects.

Comment: I am not asking if I can furnish the cottage... just create an empty Building.

Comment: Your interpretation does raise the question of what exactly counts as "an object". If "an open chest" is OK, why not "an open chest with a thick bottom that's made of gold on the inside and shaped like a pile of coins"? And if an illusory cottage can have doors and windows, what about e.g. shelves built into the walls? Would a table be OK if it was permanently attached to the floor (and how could anyone tell without touching it)? And why can an illusory coach have wheels and axles but not cushions? (Of course, none of this really matters for the OP's question.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen and it’s for this reason you have a DM with a brain to decide these things